# Can I get a jQuery object from an existing element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function

```
function toggleSelectCancels(e) {
       var checkBox = e.target;
       var cancelThis = checkBox.checked;

       var tableRow = checkBox.parentNode.parentNode;

}
```

how can I get a jQuery object that contains tableRow
Normally I would go `$("#" + tableRow.id)`, the problem here is the id for tableRow is something like this `"x:1280880471.17:adr:2:key:[95]:tag:"`. It is autogenerated by an infragistics control. jQuery doesn't seem to `getElementById` when the id is like this. the standard dom `document.getElementById("x:1280880471.17:adr:2:key:[95]:tag:")` does however return the correct row element.

Anyways, is there a way to get a jQuery object from a dom element?

Thanks,
~ck in San Diego

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Absolutely,

```
$(tableRow)
```

http://docs.jquery.com/Core/jQuery#elements

Comment: Man I love jQuery! Note - it needs to be a DOM Element as opposed to a DOM Node.

Answer (score 2):

You can call the jQuery function on DOM elements: `$(tableRow)`

You can also use the [`closest`](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/closest) method of jQuery in this case:

```
var tableRowJquery = $(checkBox).closest('tr');
```

If you want to keep using your ID, **kgiannakakis** (below), provided an excellent link on how to [escape characters with special meaning in a jQuery selector](http://docs.jquery.com/Frequently_Asked_Questions#How%5Fdo%5FI%5Fselect%5Fan%5Felement%5Fthat%5Fhas%5Fweird%5Fcharacters%5Fin%5Fits%5FID.3F).

Answer (score 2):

jQuery can take the DOM elements, try with:

```
$(tableRow)
```

or

```
$(checkBox.parentNode.parentNode)
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to pass the element straight in, like this:

```
$(tableRow)...
```

I have tested this by creating a reference to a div, then passing it straight into jQuery and it creates the jQuery object for you.

Answer (score 1):

See [this](http://docs.jquery.com/Frequently_Asked_Questions#How_do_I_select_an_element_that_has_weird_characters_in_its_ID.3F) for how you should escape the id.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
var r = $(document.getElementById("XXXX----ID Of Your Row----XXXX"));
```

now, if *document.getElementById* doesn't return undefined you can use r as any regular jquery object.